# Git Hook Script for both windows and mac

Tags: bash, git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I am trying to write a git pre-commit hook, but I need it to be compatible for both Windows and Mac (Multiple different dev machines), or at least have some way of detecting the OS and changing to the adequate environment.

I know that if set my shebang to

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe
```

then Windows will switch over to use git bash for execution.

Similarly on Mac

```
#!/bin/bash
```

sets up the bash environment for execution.

But if the hook has the wrong shebang, it won't even read it. I need a way to be able to distinguish between the OS' and set the shebang accordingly.

And creating individual hooks for mac and windows, and installing them individually on the machines is out of the question because that would make code maintenance/refactoring impossible.

Thoughts?

Comment: Store one version in git, but change the shebang line when deploying the hook to a host.

Comment: Are you sure `#!/bin/bash` at windows does not work? How about "#!/bin/sh"? As stated [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1420#issuecomment-355433179) it supposed to be working

Comment: Older windows systems (Pre windows 10) didn't have the option to enable the linux beta. 

I have however found a solution. I've been trying to write a universal git-hook for both windows and mac. I've recently found out that git-hooks will first try to run off of git's git-bash, without needing to specify the git-bash path in the shebang (which is what I was trying to do). For all intensive purposes you can leave the shebang as #!/bin/bash for both windows and mac/linux .